# Why this No Session found for current thread exceptions in spring 3.1 and hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

I was trying to configure spring 3.1 and hibernate. I have written a simple test project. where I have user domain and userDao and its implementation

let me show you may appliationContext

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.rokonoid.apps.user.dao"></context:component-scan>

<!-- Data Source -->

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/jdbc.properties" />
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.rokonoid.apps.user.domain"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">${hibernate.connection.pool_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true=1 false=0</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and part of UserDaoImpl

```
 @Repository 
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public User getUser(Long userId) {
    if (userId != null && userId > 0) {
        return (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(User.class,
                userId);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void updateUser(User user) {
    if (user != null) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(user);
    }
}
```

it seems alright. But when I was trying to run my test cases I'm this exceptions.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:881)
at com.rokonoid.apps.user.dao.UserDaoImpl.saveUser(UserDaoImpl.java:197)
at com.rokonoid.apps.test.UserDaoTest.setUserTest(UserDaoTest.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Previous problem is solved, I have got another problem : 
now I'm getting

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:328)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
```

Comment: How did you solve the first problem....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set the propagation "REQUIRED" like this:

```xml
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

I do not know whether this is a spring bug.

Answer (score 10):

There are no transactions in your sample project. Add:

```xml
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

And annotate your DAO with `@Transactional`:

```java
@Transactional
@Repository 
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao
```

Two notes:

- you are correctly marking your DAO with [`@Repository`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html), but it only handles exception translation:

  > A class thus annotated is eligible for Spring DataAccessException translation
- consider placing `@Transactional` on higher level classes (`@Service`s), see [What is the right way to use spring MVC with Hibernate in DAO, sevice layer architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993318) for discussion

Comment: thank you, but I've got another problem. Im getting another exception. just edited, can you please check it out.

Comment: But isn't it advised not to annotation DAOs with @Transactional? How can you do a "live" unit test without the @Transactional on the DAO?

Comment: @AHungerArtist: yes, I am linking to my answer describing where you should put `@Transactional`. In integration tests yuo can annotate the whole test case class.

Answer (score 1):

update to the latest jar. Their was jira created.

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8776