# @Transactional in Service layer or Facade?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the right way to use spring MVC with Hibernate in DAO, sevice layer architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993318/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-spring-mvc-with-hibernate-in-dao-sevice-layer-arch)

I have 5 main layers in my application:

1. Controller
2. Delegate
3. Service
4. Facade
5. DAO

Where should the `@Transactional` annotation go, according to the best practices?

Are there any exceptions where they can go in a Controller?

Comment: What is the difference between service and facade? A facade, by definition should be what you see from the UI layer, shouldn't it?

Comment: this question is similar to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993318/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-spring-mvc-with-hibernate-in-dao-sevice-layer-arch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A facade is what you access from outside your system. Internally it may delegate to one or multiple services. Since a facade should never contain any logic and should simply delegate to   only one service method (and not bunch multiple service calls together), it should not contain the `@Transactional` annotations. The services should have them instead.