# What is a service method?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, service, dependency-injection

I am studying Hibernate and at the same time reading articles related to DI or IOC.

While I was studying hibernate and reading articles related to DI or IOC, I've found this term called "Service" what is a service method? How does it affect your whole application?

Answer (score 1):

These days typical design (popularized by Spring and EJB to some degree) involves three layers: web, service and DAO.

Web layer should only interact with service layer (calling service methods), providing high-level, business functionality with transaction management.

Business layer should only call DAO layer (or other parts of the business layer), asking for data. Every web request can involve several business calls and every business call can involve several DAO calls.

## See also

- [What is the right way to use spring MVC with Hibernate in DAO, sevice layer architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993318)